# Incorrect syntax near '`'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a table which has spaces in table name and column name

```
create table `Table Name`
(
`User id` int,
User_name varchar(100),
Buy_dt DATE,
Sell_dt DATE
)
```

But I am getting this error. I have not copied ` symbol from anywhere and typing backticks from my laptop only

```
Incorrect syntax near '`'.
```

Comment: It's `[User id]` for SQL Server.

Comment: Those backticks are for MySQL. As Zhorov said, use square brackets.

Comment: works. brackets both for table n columns

Comment: I suggest to avoid the necessity of quoting column names by not using blanks, special characters and keywords at all. Just: `user_id int` as you already did with the other column names. (Same for table names of course, e.g. `table_name`.)

Comment: Adding to Thorsten's command regarding blanks, instead of proprietary backticks or proprietary `[]` you better switch to Standard SQL *double quoted names* (which is supported by both MySQL and SQL Server): `"User id"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using square brackets for columns descriptions that have spaces and not an accepted character like "_". So, in your case, you may use:

```
create table [Table Name]
(
[User id] int,
User_name varchar(100),
Buy_dt DATE,
Sell_dt DATE
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to point out that SQL Server now also supports double quotes, which is the standard for escaping identifiers:

```
create table "Table Name" (
    "User id" int,
    User_name varchar(100),
    Buy_dt DATE,
    Sell_dt DATE
);
```